# What do I do after studying the basics of Python?

Tags: python

If someone now studies the basics of the Python what should he do after that? Are there specific books he must read? Or, what exactly?

In other words, what is the pathway to mastering Python?

Thanks

Comment: It's the same formula with Python as in any programming language. Practice makes perfect. IMO you can try different programming problems online, like [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/).

Answer (score 7):

Write *a lot* of code (to solve your own problems, and/or participate in open source projects), hang out here, learn from the questions and then try to contribute.

I have learned *a lot* of things on SO, sometimes it's a bit harsh around here, but so far it's been definitely worth it. I've been made aware of some corners of Python I didn't even know existed.

The feedback you get (usually constructive) and the *many (many!) alternative* solutions you see to the same problem can be incredibly useful.

You can also set yourself some concrete goals (such as mastering Regular Expressions) and then dive into that with readings and exercises (and following those tags on SO).

=> At the end there's no substitute for actually writing code though.

ps: Working some of the [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) problems has taught me the value of carefully thinking about data structures and algorithms even more than I had before, as the problems can be non-trivial and resistent to brute-force approaches. This too has made me a better progammer, and has been both challenging and fun.

Comment: +1 I totally agree, I learned a lot on StackOveflow.

Comment: I still learn a lot on SO ...

Answer (score 2):

Get a project you are interested in, **start hacking** (i.e. extend it, fix small bugs you encounter). There are a lot of opensource projects out there you can checkout.

You need experience, and experience comes from failing, failing is a result of trying. That's your way to go.

If you get stuck somewhere, always check back to SO or google - that will aid you fixing 99.9% of your issues.

Answer (score 1):

Start writing useful code.  Learn object oriented Python. Learn enough to answer questions on SO.

Do the [Python Challege](http://www.pythonchallenge.com)

Comment: Seriously, you just had to post the link to Python Challenge, didn't you. As if I wasn't spending enough time on SO and Project Euler already  .. sigh ... :)